# photogragher drupal site with thousands of images to sell

Tags: php, drupal

I'm developing a site in drupal for a photographer that needs to put online thousands of images each weekend and then sell them through the site, with ubercart i think; He takes photos on a circuit to users that pay to race with their vehicles and very often they want to buy pictures of their journeys. I would NOT like to "import" each photo as a node, doing so i'll have thousands and thoudsands of nodes uselessly, instead i would like to show images in galleries (galleries for me will be nodes, or something similar) i found the gallery2 drupal integration module and i was thinking about using this to show galleries and let the users buy only "prints" of pictures, integrating it with ubercart system, so the only node i would like to manage are galleries and product nodes such as 10x15 print, 30x20 print and so on.  Which are the modules to best solve this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CCK modules to create "galleries" of images, where the node is the gallery, and you can upload a theoretically infinitesimal amount of images to it.

These modules can work in conjunction to make that happen:

- http://drupal.org/project/cck
- http://drupal.org/project/filefield
- http://drupal.org/project/imagefield

As for resizing images [imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) will help you do that, however some more thought will be needed on how to deliver those "purchases" to your customers. That is potentially another question.

Comment: yes, but are you sure i can manage thousands of images oh that field ?

Answer (score 0):

DragnDrop Uploads and Image_FUpload also work with imagefield, which may make image uploading easier for batch uploads:

- http://drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads
- http://drupal.org/project/image_fupload

As suggested by Amateur Barista, I think CCK is the way to go, I don't think the number of images will be a problem. Just make sure it's not running on a slow server.

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I ended up using image-jupload, which is a java applet that lets you upload multiple images at once.  There's a flash one that I could never get to work reliably.

I would create a gallery before uploading and then this makes nodes for each image.

My notes are a little old, but this may be the one: http://drupal.org/node/180616

Hope that helps.

Comment: i think it can be ok, but i need to sell (and upload) thousands of images, i tried to upload hundreds but, via javascript too, the cck forms on edit node page become very slow... i can't imagine with thousands of them :-) So i was searching for a more pragmatic solutions: not having each image as a node, but using only 3 or for product nodes (as print formats, eg. small, medium, big etc) order only them but specifying wich photo/image to print on that size.

Comment: My site has between 50 and 300 photos in each gallery and performance is fine so far.  I don't have a lot of galleries online yet, so the total photo count is still low which may affect performance.  I fought with the bulk uploading for so long that I've been taking a looong break from drupal.